# What would i need to make this software (python)?

Tags: python, software-development

Hello i am trying to make an app for my first real python project. I have been coding for 1 year.

I want to make an app that gets a video (mp4 file) and outputs the video as a live stream camera to another computer through usb. one computer cannot have anything installed on it! (defeats the purpose of me coding it)

so Laptop 1: has a video on it

Laptop 2: I cannot install anything on it gets the usb source as a camera

What pacakge/s would i need besides tinker to export the video through the usb and make it show up as a camera?

Comment: That sounds completely unrealistic for one laptop to act as a camera for another laptop. I would recommend reading on how regular USB cables work. Why would you ever want to do that anyways? Classic XY problem. I would also recommend checking what HDMI capture cards are and why they'd be a kind of solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can set up a file system so that python can access the discs of "Computer 1" and "Computer 2", and the computer that is the camera will have a script that will transmit 30-60 times per second photos from the camera, and the computer that will output the video will 30-60 times per second output these photos in a loop.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/66794)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).